Unable to upgrade Mesa on Debian
I am running Debian with kernel 6.5-asahi on an Apple M1 MacBook Air. Although I have kernel 6.9 installed, if I boot into it Mesa goes into software acceleration mode.
apt upgrade gives
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm-dev libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libosmesa6   
  lsp-plugins-lv2 lsp-plugins-r3d-glx m1n1 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

apt full-upgrade gives
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-asahi u-boot-asahi
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl-mesa0 libgbm-dev libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libosmesa6
  lsp-plugins-lv2 lsp-plugins-r3d-glx m1n1 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

Here's my dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl-mesa0:arm64                               23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libegl1-mesa-dev:arm64                           24.2.0-20240527+cy8aer0                   arm64        free implementation of the EGL API -- development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev:arm64                            24.2.0-20240527+cy8aer0                   arm64        transitional dummy package
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:arm64                            23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libglapi-mesa:arm64                              23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:arm64                               9.0.2-1.1                                 arm64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev:arm64                           9.0.2-1.1                                 arm64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libglx-mesa0:arm64                               23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  libosmesa6:arm64                                 23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  mesa-common-dev:arm64                            24.2.0-20240527+cy8aer0                   arm64        Developer documentation for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                                       8.5.0-1                                   arm64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilities -- symlinks
ii  mesa-utils-bin:arm64                             8.5.0-1                                   arm64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilities -- native applications
ii  mesa-va-drivers:arm64                            23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        Mesa VA-API video acceleration drivers
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:arm64                         23.0.0-202310051950                       arm64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers

How can I cleanly upgrade mesa without screwing the system? These versions of Mesa are from a 3rd party repo, which also contains the linux-image-asahi which is odd that they conflict. The versions of Mesa I am trying to upgrade are from the repo, not from deb.debian.org, and I've set a very high pin priority to the 3rd party repos in apt
The 3rd party repos are
deb https://git.g3la.de/api/packages/repos/debian testing main
deb https://thomas.glanzmann.de/asahi testing main

As an example of manually installing one of the replacement packages:
nick@MacBook:~$ sudo apt install libegl-mesa0
[sudo] password for nick: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl-mesa0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.36-9+deb12u7 is to be installed
                Depends: libgbm1 (= 24.2.0-20240527+cy8aer0) but 23.0.0-202310051950 is to be installed
                Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 24.2.0-20240527+cy8aer0) but 23.0.0-202310051950 is to be installed
                Depends: libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.8.7) but 2:1.8.4-2+deb12u2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Please provide the output of at least 1 package upgrade that's been held back, i.e. what is the output of: apt install libegl-mesa0  determining the reason the package is held back will help determine the solution.

@eyoung100
Too long to fit in comment, updated the question at the bottom.
It seems they require a newer version of many packages. Although I do have Debian Unstable in the repo's, I'm reluctant to set Unstable at a higher pin priority (plus the M1 Debian repo says it's for Debian testing)

It looks like you're stuck.  All Debian M1 work is in the testing phase.  See Installing on M1 and Asahi Reference Implementation and the bootstrap reference

DANGEROUS
Ended up purging every mesa* package, doing an apt full-upgrade and reinstalling Mesa. This half-updated state the system was in didn't suit me so I was willing to take the risk. Worked like a charm!
